# Entire Magento site is HTTPS?

Tags: cache, ssl, https

we recently installed an SSL certificate and configured Magento as recommended;

1. Set Web>Secure to https://
2. Set use secure in frontend and backend to yes

Now, every single page on our site is automatically HTTPS - I know this is not normal behaviour but I have confirmed there are not rewrites in the htaccess, the unsecure url is set to http:// and we only have basic extensions (with Extendware's Full Page Cache).

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Using `Set use secure in frontend and backend` to yes is making your entire site secure. If you want to use it only in certain pages, disable that option.

Comment: That's already set to yes :(

Comment: That is why I'm telling you to set it to No.

Comment: even after setting it to no, all pages show as https :(

Comment: If you set it to `yes` and afterwards the whole site was `https` then setting it to `no` will revert it back to normal. If that's not the case for you, make sure to flush the cache and reindex. If it still doesn't work you will need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can put non-secure urls as https:// .... in this way your whole website will be on SSL, but remember it could slow down your website speed up to some extant specially if you used subdomain as CDN.

Comment: I'm looking to make it so only checkout/login etc are https, the rest I wantto be http

Comment: then you only need to update secure urls as https:// leave un-secure as http://  .... its normal procedure in Magento but since Google preferred SSL for SEO too, you can consider.

Answer (score 0):

Via admin go to System > Configuration > Web > Unsecure and put the base URL as https to get https on all pages
[image: Unsecure Base URL]

Comment: I'm looking to set only checkout/login to https, the rest I want to http as normal